# Building SDL2 - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, libiconv

Tags: c++, sdl, libiconv

I have downloaded SDL2 and am trying to build it using the terminal command

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/SDL && make && make install
```

It runs through a laundry list of things, before eventually stopping after spitting out:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _SDL_iconv in SDL_iconv.o
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _SDL_iconv_close in SDL_iconv.o
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _SDL_iconv_open in SDL_iconv.o
      _SDL_iconv_string in SDL_iconv.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/libSDL2.la] Error 1
```

I have hunted and hunted and have no idea what to do about this. Help?

EDIT:

Breaking it up, ./configure alone works, and then running make afterwords throws up these errors. I don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install libiconv.  Then rerun the make